# Bootstrap 4.1 - Flex items - Align to left (only last line)

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

How can I fix it with bootstrap, that the items of the last line, be aligned at the left?

```css
img{
  max-width: 137px;
}
li{
  display: inline-block
}
ul{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w-100">
<ul class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="img-fluid flex-fill"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flex-fill` is making the items grow to maximize width. Remove `flex-fill`, and just use padding...

```
<div class="w-100">
    <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap">
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li class="px-4"><img src="https://www.peregrineadventures.com/sites/peregrine/files/styles/low-quality/public/elements/product/hero/russia.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/OLNl0s8D2y